# GWT with DateTime ( Checking giving day is in valid days )

Tags: java, date, datetime, gwt

I want to get rich facilities concerns with **Date** in **GWT** as like [JAVA Calendar Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). But unfortunately , I can't use it in client side due to that is not in [Emulation Classes](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_util). I am so lazy not only to write hard code but also to import another libraries , so I want to get ready made functions these are made by **GWT**.

My problem is checking given day , is that in valid days range ?

```
*Condition depends on Today
```

- If today <= 3 ( valid days range is **from** *fist day of previous month*  **to** *today*)
- else  ( valid days range is **from** *fist day of this month*  **to** *today*)

Here my codes...

```
    private boolean isInValidDateRange(final Date checkDate) {
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    int currentDay = Integer.parseInt(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd").format(todayDate));
    Date startDate = null;
    // End date will always today
    Date endDate = new Date();
    if (currentDay <= 3) {
        // shift to previous month
        CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate(todayDate, -1);
        // set to first day of month
        CalendarUtil.setToFirstDayOfMonth(todayDate);
        startDate = todayDate;

    }
    else {
        // set to first day of month
        CalendarUtil.setToFirstDayOfMonth(todayDate);
        startDate = todayDate;
    }
    return (CalendarUtil.getDaysBetween(startDate, checkDate) >= 0 && 
            CalendarUtil.getDaysBetween(checkDate,endDate) >= 0);
}
```

I googled many times to get answers for my problems. But most of them lead to ***Java Calendar*** Object.

My question is how to get it by easy way or can I convert it to simply codes?

Comment: If this method works for all tests cases and runs "fast enough", I don't think is a good idea to have the extra effort scrubbing bits.
Avoid premature optimization, here is an article that help explain [why](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451)
PS: I would have implemented using CalendarUtil as well. Maybe I'd just have used the `Date.getDate()` instead of a new instance of  `DateTimeFormat`

Comment: @André .. Yeah , nice idea for Date.getDate() great !

Answer (score 0):

you can use Sencha GXT DateWrapper instead of implement Java Calendar

[date wrapper docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/core/client/util/DateWrapper.Unit.html)

Comment: I didn't tag with gxt. but thanks for your useful answer.But I would like to create with simple GWT or simply java codes.

Comment: DateWrapper not a GXT specific code, you can copy its source code for you.