# getting numbers day between two dates range include start date and end date

Tags: java, gwt

How to get number of days between two dates range including start date and end date.
The start date is stored t3 as 20140221 in string.
The end date is stored t4 as 20140315 in string.
How to get The number of days between these two dates in java and gwt.
how to get range of dates with respective day between two given dates.

for example:-

from 10/10/2004 to 14/10/2004 range of dates are

10/10/2004 sunday
11/10/2004 monday
12/10/2004 tuesday
13/10/2004 wednesday
14/10/2004 thursday

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
private ArrayList<Date> searchDatesBetween(Date stdate,Date endate)
{
    ArrayList<Date> searchList=new ArrayList<Date>();
Date begin=new Date(stdate.getTime());
searchList.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));
while(begin.compareTo(endate)<0){           
begin=new Date(begin.getTime()+864000);     
searchList.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));
}
return searchList;
}
```

> Blockquote

```
void onButCreateRosterClick(ClickEvent event) {
    DateTimeFormat l_format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE-dd/MM/yyyy");   
    Date stdate=new Date();
    Date endate=new Date(); 
    dateList=new ArrayList<Date>();     

    stDateOfRoster=mRosterList.get(indexofdate).getT3();
    enDateOfRoster=mRosterList.get(indexofdate).getT4();
    codeOfShift=mShiftList.get(indexofshift).getT1();
    stdate=l_format.parse(stDateOfRoster);
    endate=l_format.parse(enDateOfRoster);

    dateList=searchDatesBetween(stdate,endate);
}
```

Comment: Any code to start with ?

Comment: For the love of god, how to get is not proper English. At least say how do I get, please!

Comment: @Suresh - This is not a duplicate. That question was about Java. This one - about GWT.

Comment: with **GWT** . pls check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208749/gwt-with-datetime-checking-giving-day-is-in-valid-days)

Answer (score 0):

Try  [Days](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html) class in version 1.4 of Joda-Time.

```
Days d = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);
int days = d.getDays();
```

Comment: Joda-Time doesn't work in GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Parse both dates and use CalendarUitl. For example:

```
Date startDate = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_SHORT).parseStrict(value1);
Date endDate = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_SHORT).parseStrict(value2);
int days = CalendarUtil.getDaysBetween(startDate, endDate);
```